# How can I check the parity of transcendental functions?

Tags: parity, transcendental-functions

I know how to check it in general ($f(x)=f(-x)$) but I don't understand how I can check it for any transcendental functions, because I cannot check if (for example) $\tan(x)= \tan(-x)$

Comment: It suffices to note that $\tan(-x) = \frac{\sin(-x)}{\cos(-x)}$

Comment: There is no one method that will work for *any* function, if that's what you're really trying to ask

Comment: Hint : $\ \sin(-x)=-\sin(x)\ $ and $\ \cos(-x)=\cos(x)\ $

Comment: How do you know that Peter?

Comment: Look at the power series expansion for $\sin(x)$, it has only odd powers.  On the other hand, the power series for $\cos(x)$ has only even powers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The following is to clarify some concepts and is too long to put in the comment column above.**

Not all transcendental functions are purely odd or even.  For example,

\begin{align*}
  e^{-x} & \ne -e^{x} \\
  e^{-x} & \ne e^{x}
\end{align*}

However, we can artificially redefine a new function from old.

\begin{align*}
  g(x) &= \frac{f(x)+f(-x)}{2} \\
  \implies g(-x) &= g(x) \\
  h(x) &= \frac{f(x)-f(-x)}{2} \\
  \implies h(-x) &= -h(x) \\
\end{align*}

- Now $g(x)$ is even and $h(x)$ is odd.
- $g(x)+h(x)=f(x)$ that recovers $f(x)$.
- $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ can be regarded as the even and odd components of $f(x)$ respectively.

In particular,
\begin{align*}
  \cosh x &= \frac{e^{x}+e^{-x}}{2} \\
  \sinh x &= \frac{e^{x}-e^{-x}}{2} \\
\end{align*}

Also,
\begin{align*}
  \cos x &= \frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2} \\
  \sin x &= \frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i} \\
\end{align*}

> In your case:
>   \begin{align*}
>   \tan x &= \frac{\sin x}{\cos x} \\
>   &= \frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}} \\
>   \tan (-x) &= \frac{e^{-ix}+e^{ix}}{e^{-ix}-e^{ix}} \\
>   &= -\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}} \\
>   &= -\tan x
> \end{align*}
>   which is odd.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question (even though it's an interesting thing to note).

Comment: Yes, I'd like to clarify the concepts instead.

Comment: Is there no other way than to use exponentials?

Comment: It's quite elementary by observing the **CAST** rule or [**A**ll-**S**tudent-**T**ake-**C**alculus Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_Students_Take_Calculus)